# objShell.Run changes with Windows 10 v1909

Tags: vba, windows, vbscript

Since I upgraded to the newer version 1909 last week, simple Outlook macros no longer work.

I want to execute batches and VBS scripts via button.

My code is e.g:

```
Sub busy()
strPath = "C:\Users\xxxxxxx\Documents\Addons\busy.vbs"
Set objShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
objShell.Run strPath, 1, False
End Sub
```

I get the error message since the update:

> ```
> Runtime error '-2147024894 (80070002)':  
> The method "Run" for the object "IWshShell3" failed.
> ```

What do I have to change to make it work again? The call ran wonderfully before.
Opening the scripts manually, e.g. via Windows Explorer, is no problem.

Comment: It is the (secret) script to debug, not Access.

Comment: What happens when you open a command prompt and enter `C:\Users\xxxxxxx\Documents\Addons\busy.vbs`?

Comment: 80070002 is file not found. Use [Process Monitor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon) with a filter set to `Path` `ends with` `busy.vbs` to see which actual path the code _attempts_ to access; maybe there are some filesystem redirection shenanigans going on. Or maybe case-sensitivity was turned on for one of the folders in the hierarchy by accident and the file isn't called `busy.vbs` but e.g. `Busy.vbs` or `busy.VBS` or whatever

Comment: You can then also run the script manually where it works, and compare both invocations in Process Monitor to find the difference.

Comment: Any spaces in the path? Then try `strPath = """C:\Users\xxxxxxx\Documents\Addons\busy.vbs"""`

Comment: The spaces are the problem - THANKS >.< I only tried ""PATH"" and "PATH" ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there are spaces in the path make sure your path is sourunded by quotes:

```
strPath = """C:\Users\xxx xx xx\Documents\Addons\busy.vbs"""
```